# У меня в 1с битриксе в поиске не выскакивают подсказки

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайта подключен поиск, он работает в пк версии, а в мобильной нет

Код пк и моб версии хедера разделен по html и css медиа

Если копировать его в моб версию, то перестает работать и в пк версии, и в моб не отрабатывает

```html
<?

$INPUT_ID = trim($arParams["~INPUT_ID"]);
if(strlen($INPUT_ID) <= 0)
    $INPUT_ID = "title-search-input";
$INPUT_ID = CUtil::JSEscape($INPUT_ID);

$CONTAINER_ID = trim($arParams["~CONTAINER_ID"]);
if(strlen($CONTAINER_ID) <= 0)
    $CONTAINER_ID = "title-search";
$CONTAINER_ID = CUtil::JSEscape($CONTAINER_ID);
if($_REQUEST['q']){
    $_REQUEST['q'] = urldecode($_REQUEST['q']);
}
if($arParams["SHOW_INPUT"] !== "N"):?>            

                        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    $_REQUEST['TEST'] == 'Y' ,
    "top_search",
    array(
        "NUM_CATEGORIES" => "1",
        "TOP_COUNT" => "5",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "N",
        "SHOW_OTHERS" => "Y",
        "PAGE" => stristr($APPLICATION->GetCurDir(), '/cosmetics/')? "#SITE_DIR#/cosmetics/search/index.php": "#SITE_DIR#search/index.php",
        "CATEGORY_0_TITLE" => GetMessage("SEARCH_GOODS"),
        "CATEGORY_0" => array(
            0 => "iblock_catalog",
        ),
        "CATEGORY_0_iblock_catalog" => array(
            0 => "14",
            1 => "18",
        ),
        "CATEGORY_OTHERS_TITLE" => GetMessage("SEARCH_OTHER"),
        "SHOW_INPUT" => "Y",
        "INPUT_ID" => "title-search-input",
        "CONTAINER_ID" => "search",
        "ORDER" => "date",
        "USE_LANGUAGE_GUESS" => "Y",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "top_search",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(
        ),
        "PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE" => "Y",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SHOW_PREVIEW" => "Y",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N"
    ),
    false
);?>
 <p class="icon-header"><a href="#" class="div-block-96 w-inline-block js-search-btn search-btn-top"><img src="/img/search-icon.svg" alt="Эстелаб" class=""></a></p>
 <div id="<?echo $CONTAINER_ID?>" class="bx_search_container">
    <form  accept-charset="utf-8" method="get" action="<?echo $arResult["FORM_ACTION"]?>">
        <div class="bx_field">
            <input id="<?echo $INPUT_ID?>" type="text" name="q" value="<?=htmlspecialcharsbx($_REQUEST["q"])?>" autocomplete="off" class="bx_input_text" placeholder="Поиск"/>
            <input name="s" type="submit" value="" class="bx_input_submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
 <?endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с проблемой моб и пк версии, он в одном файле плохо влиял на повторную работу одного компонента, поэтому в моб версии компонент я убрал под условие определения моб версии

```html
<?
function check_mobile_device() { 
    $mobile_agent_array = array('ipad', 'iphone', 'android', 'pocket', 'palm', 'windows ce', 'windowsce', 'cellphone', 'opera mobi', 'ipod', 'small', 'sharp', 'sonyericsson', 'symbian', 'opera mini', 'nokia', 'htc_', 'samsung', 'motorola', 'smartphone', 'blackberry', 'playstation portable', 'tablet browser');
    $agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    foreach ($mobile_agent_array as $value) {
        if (strpos($agent, $value) !== false) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
if (check_mobile_device()):
?>

...Тут html код

<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: А в поддержку Битрикс не обращались? Они могли посмотреть и дать ответ, который либо помог Вам, либо стал сигналом к изобретательству новых, красивых, изящных костылей.